# SpringBoot 3 RestTemplate set readtimeout or responsetimeout per each request

Tags: spring-boot-3, apache-httpclient-5.x

Single RestTemplate Bean which is initialized with default connection timeout properties.

But if you need custom timeout or specific readtimeout , you can update the RequestFactory of the Resttemplate

Try implementing HttpComponentClientRequestFactory which will replace default SimpleclientRequestFactory

1. create your custom class

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;



public class MyHttpCompClientHttpReqFactory  extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {

    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHttpCompClientHttpReqFactory.class);

    private CustomRequestProps customRequestProps =null;
    
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
            if(customRequestProps!=null) {
              HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
              RequestConfig requestConfig = createRequestConfig(getHttpClient());  // Get default request config and modify timeouts as specified
              long defaultResponseTimeout=requestConfig.getResponseTimeout().toMilliseconds();
              
              RequestConfig customReqConfig = RequestConfig.copy(requestConfig)
                  .setResponseTimeout(customRequestProps.getResponseTimeoutMillis(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                  .setConnectTimeout(customRequestProps.getConnectionTimeoutMillis(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                  .setConnectionRequestTimeout(customRequestProps.getConnectionRequestTimeoutMillis(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                  .build();
              context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.REQUEST_CONFIG, customReqConfig);
              
              long customResponseTimeout=requestConfig.getResponseTimeout().toMilliseconds();
              log.info("MyHttpCompClientHttpReqFactory defaultResponseTimeout "+defaultResponseTimeout+" customResponseTimeout "+customResponseTimeout);
              return context;
            }
            return null;// continue with actual method in HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory
             
      }
      
      protected CustomRequestProps initCustomRequestConfigProps(int connectionTimeoutMillis,
              int connectionRequestTimeoutMillis,
              int responseTimeoutMillis) {
          this.customRequestProps=new CustomRequestProps(connectionTimeoutMillis,
                   connectionRequestTimeoutMillis,
                   responseTimeoutMillis);
          return customRequestProps;
      }

      private class  CustomRequestProps  {
        
          int connectionTimeoutMillis;
          int connectionRequestTimeoutMillis;
          int responseTimeoutMillis;
       
          CustomRequestProps(int connectionTimeoutMillis,
          int connectionRequestTimeoutMillis,
          int responseTimeoutMillis){
              this.connectionTimeoutMillis=connectionTimeoutMillis;
              this.connectionRequestTimeoutMillis=connectionRequestTimeoutMillis;
              this.responseTimeoutMillis=responseTimeoutMillis;
          }

        public int getConnectionTimeoutMillis() {
            return connectionTimeoutMillis;
        }

        public int getConnectionRequestTimeoutMillis() {
            return connectionRequestTimeoutMillis;
        }

        public int getResponseTimeoutMillis() {
            return responseTimeoutMillis;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CustomRequestProps [connectionTimeoutMillis=" + connectionTimeoutMillis
                    + ", connectionRequestTimeoutMillis=" + connectionRequestTimeoutMillis + ", responseTimeoutMillis="
                    + responseTimeoutMillis + "]";
        }
        
        
        

        
      }
    }
```

2. invoke custom class

```
yourImplclass.java

  @Autowired
  RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public invokeApi(String requestBody){
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(getRequestFactory(timeout));
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, method, requestHttpEntity,new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {
                        });
  }


   private ClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactory(int inputTimeOutMillis) {
         MyHttpCompClientHttpReqFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new MyHttpCompClientHttpReqFactory ();
         clientHttpRequestFactory.initCustomRequestConfigProps(10, 20, 30);
        return clientHttpRequestFactory;
    }
```